# Qt QSpinbox and QPushButton to Arduino

Tags: c++, qt, arduino, qpushbutton, qspinbox

I am a new leaner of Qt. Here's the project I am doing right now, I would like to adjust the LED luminosity from Qt's GUI. All I need are the `QSpinBox` to enter the value of luminosity(0~255) and the `QPushButton` to confirm the value and send this signal to Arduino to execute. But I don't know what kind of commands for this GUI. Here is my Arduino code:

```
const int ledPin = 9;
int ledlum;
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(ledPin, 0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()){
    ledlum = Serial.parseInt();
    write_led(ledlum);
  }
}

void write_led(int lum){
   analogWrite(ledPin, 0 + lum);
}
```

[My GUI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBihy.jpg)

So I can type the value of lum (0~255) to adjust the LED luminosity. Hope you guys could help me out here. Provide some example or code. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Macive

Comment: Are you asking how to get the values / events from the ui or how to send that value to the arduino?

Comment: I solved the QSpinBox problem and now I am solving the QPushButton, I would like the Button waiting for my command to send the value into Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

To link the QPushButton to your code, you need signals and slots. You could use the QPushButton::clicked() signal in order to submit the value in the SpinBox. 
You could connect this signal to another slot function using the QObject::connect() function.
 But only QObjects or its children.
I suggest you read Qt's documentation on signals and slots from here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html